# System.ArgumentException Requested value was not found

Tags: c#, c++, dll

I have a C# Aplication they use a C++ .dll.

When I call a method from the dll, I get an: `System.ArgumentException. Requested value 'C:\test\test.csv' was not found`.

The file really dies exist at this path and I have a C++ application that uses this .dll and it work well.

```
TESTData.Convert.ToPRODFile("C:\\test\\test.csv");
```

The role of this method is to convert and write a file.

Does someone have an idea for this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the right exception ? I mean there may be another problem which this message is thrown instead, of course if the file does not exist. Do you have the dll source code ?